# Anyone got a SOCKS4/5 proxy client for linux that supports username and password?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, socks

I **do not want** a **http(s) client**, I **do not want** a **ftp client**

I need a **SOCKS4/4a/5 client** that supports **username + password authentication**. Sorry for the bold text, just gotta make sure I clarify it well enough, I have been searching the internet with no avail for a client that allows me this, the Gnome settings one doesn't support authentication and every other client is HTTP(S)/FTP or Windows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup [privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) which [supports SOCKS authentication](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#SOCKS) to connect to your SOCKS proxy. It will work as a forwarding HTTP proxy with a local address like `127.0.0.1:8118` that you can then set into Gnome settings.

So minimal `privoxy` configuration would look like this

```
listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118

forward-socks5 / user:pass@<SOCKS_ADDRESS>:<SOCKS_PORT> .

confdir /etc/privoxy

logdir /var/log/privoxy
logfile logfile
```

Comment: I get `Privoxy was unable to socks5-forward your request http://a/ through xproot: invalid gateway port specified` no idea why, checked the docs and it seems my config is right

Also is there a way to make the privoxy server be socks?

Comment: `invalid gateway port specified` error occurs when you forget to specify socks port, please check your configuration. And unfortunately no, `privoxy` can work only as a http-to-socks forwarder. If you are trying to chain socks proxies, then maybe you'd better try using [proxychains](https://github.com/haad/proxychains).

Comment: my config is this `forward-socks5  /       xproot:mypassword@server:6800 .` what's wrong?

Comment: Hm. Everything looks exactly as it says in the docs. Did you restart `privoxy` after making changes to the config?

Comment: I found the problem, the packages in Ubuntu 20.04 are outdated, got a updated deb at the site, works flawlessly now :D, can you help me set up a working https proxy too? privoxy supports that but i can't seem to get it work
EDIT: seems the update fixed it as well! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that everything works! :) By the way, if you really need socks server to forward to another socks, you can try running socks server like [dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/) or [microsocks](https://github.com/rofl0r/microsocks) through `proxychains`.